# Using 'defined' with 'ifdef'?

Tags: c, programming-languages

consider the snippet below:

```
#ifdef AAA && (defined BBB)
...
#endif
```

gcc-4.5.2 complains on this line:

> > extra tokens at the end of #ifdef directive.

Is it illegal to combine `ifdef` and `defined` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The `#ifdef` requires a single identifier and is equivalent to `#if defined(identifier)`.

You need to use the `#if` directive if you have a more complex expression:

```
#if (defined AAA) && (defined BBB) // true if AAA and BBB are both defined
#if AAA && (defined BBB)           // true if AAA is true and BBB is defined
```

Answer (score 5):

`#ifdef` will only work on one token.
If you want to use more than one then write

`#if defined(AAA) && defined(BBB)`